# How to resolve ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to get this program to work however I cant see how to resolve the error message displayed when run.

Here is the code I am running;

```
import pyttsx   # text-to-speech library
engine = pyttsx.init()   # initiates speech engine
engine.say('Hello World')   # loads text into engine
engine.runAndWait()   # THIS LINE IS IMPORTANT, runs the speech engine
```

`
And here is the error message;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "V:/testing/test1.py", line 3, in <module>
        engine = pyttsx.init()   # initiates speech engine
    File "V:\testing\set 10\lib\site-packages\pyttsx\__init__.py", line 39, in init
        eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
    File "V:\testing\set 10\lib\site-packages\pyttsx\engine.py", line 45, in __init__
        self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
    File "V:\testing\set 10\lib\site-packages\pyttsx\driver.py", line 64, in __init__
        self._module = __import__(name, globals(), locals(), [driverName])
    File "V:\testing\set 10\lib\site-packages\pyttsx\drivers\sapi5.py", line 19, in <module>
        import win32com.client
    File "V:\testing\set 10\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
        import win32api, sys, os
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I am using Pycharm Community Edition with python 2.7.13. This program is one of the first steps to be taken while attempting to follow this(http://letsmakerobots.com/node/41226) toutorial.

I have the following packages installed;
pip - 9.0.1, pyttsx - 1.1, pywin32 - 219, setuptools - 33.1.0, wheel - 0.29.0

Any advice or answers would greatly be appreciated, Theo.

Comment: What windows version?  Have you tried without the virtual environment?

Comment: windows 10, I didn't know I was using a virtual environment, What exactly are you referring to?

Comment: Virtual Environments are a way to manage python packages for different projects.  I though you might be using them because your packages are in `V:\testing\set 10\lib` which is not the path I am used to seeing libraries in.  I know some versions of the win32 api have had problems with virtual environments.  If you are just starting out, then you likely do not need virtual environments, and I was going to suggest turning them off.  Would suggest googling pycharm and virtual environments.

Comment: Ah I sere, Im not using a Virtual Enviorment, I partitioned my Hard drive so I can work on this project Seperatly without any interference, meaning I installed the programs onto that. Unless you think that could have any effect?

Comment: There appears to be something wrong with the win32com package.

Comment: I tried updating it to the latest version and when it finishes it says; `Close failed in file object destructor sys.excepthook is missing, lost sys.stderr` any ideas? @StephenRauch

Comment: I have no particular advice, except maybe try a standard install configuration.